# Properly graph a scatterplot series using python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a hard time getting matplotlib pyplot (import matplotlib.pyplot as plt) to properly graph a data series on a scatter plot.  I have the following series where:

```
x = [0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.45,0.5,0.55,0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,1]
y =[94.71,96.26,97.29,97.91,98.19,98.18,97.92,97.44,96.75,95.86,94.75,93.43,91.87,90.04,87.90,85.43,82.55,79.22,75.35,70.88,65.71]
```

When I go to plot this series using plt.plot(x, y)  I get the wrong behavior where the graph simply shows up as a diagonal line (it seems matplotlib may have automatically sorted the values for the y axis).

The correct graph behavior which I expect to get should have been a downward concave curve if each of the x value in the x list is paired with the corresponding y value in the y list.  I have no idea how to get matplotlib to graph it properly to where it shows up as a concave downward curve instead of a diagonal line.

Comment: It works fine for me. Moreover, to get a scatter plot, either use `plt.scatter(x,y)` or use plt.plot(x, y, 'bo') where `o` is the marker symbol for a circle and `b` is blue color

Comment: Copy the code from your own question and paste it to a file, run it, and you will get the correct curve. For any other problem, make sure to provide a [mcve].